# How to understand information as energy?

Tags: energy, computer-arithmetic

Cpu or gpu making calculations and creating information (decrease in entropy) is converting 100% of energy it pulls from the wall into heat.

How should we understand the created order in terms of spent energy? I feel like there is some obvious fallacy in my logic but couldn't properly formulate it.

Some related thoughts:

1. It should in theory be possible to create computers that consume no
   energy at all.
2. A light bulb creates light but still converts all the energy into heat, eventually. There might be a parallelism between the light and information created by processors.

Comment: Quantum computations are *theoretically* fully reversible. That is no information is lost (converted) in such a computation.

Comment: Relevant reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landauer%27s_principle

Comment: @EugeneSh. A processor that computes if a very big number is a prime or not, did it create no information? How could this information be created for free? The information existed in some platonic sense, but the before computing the processor didn't know it and know it knows.

Comment: @AhmetSaidAK If you are really interested in the topic, you will need to do some learning/research. Quantum computations are represented as unitary transformations on "input" vectors (qubit states). Unitary transformations are reversible. This is math and physics (and quite applied recently), not philosophy.

Comment: So the information exists in the non-platonic sense, and the quantum system *knows* the number is prime in the same sense as a falling body "knows" it's acceleration. It is embedded into it's physics. Quantum computers and classical computer are totally different things.

Comment: "A light bulb creates light but still converts all the energy into heat" Not all; a small percent is converted into photons.

Comment: @EugeneSh. thank you, I'd appreciate any suggestions for further reading.

Comment: @rdtsc A photon will be absorbed and converted into heat eventually (almost immediately).

Comment: @AhmetSaidAK There used to be a great intro course by Prof. Umesh Vazirani on both Coursera and Edx, but looks like it was discontinued. You can still find his lectures on Youtube though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the relationship between non-reversible computing (where bits are discarded), temperature and energy as described by the  [Landauer Limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landauer%27s_principle)

If bits are not discarded into the environment but "recycled" by [Reversible Computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_computing) then this limit can be circumvented to some degree. However, just reading the result of the computation will cost energy